# Sort table with Matlab

Tags: matlab, sorting

I am a beginner in Matlab and want to sort a simple table. I have a table with numbers and letters in .txt format:

```
K L M  N  O
1 1 a1 3b 1.72
2 1 2c 4d 1.43
3 1 e3 5f 1.33
4 1 g4 h5 1.64
1 2 4i 4j 1.48
2 2 6k l8 2.33
3 2 m7 8n 2.12
4 2 o8 p0 1.92
```

Now I want so sort this table using Matlab. What I want to have is:

```
K L M  N  O
1 1 a1 3b 1.72
1 2 4i 4j 1.48    
2 1 2c 4d 1.43
2 2 6k l8 2.33
3 1 e3 5f 1.33
3 2 m7 8n 2.12
4 1 g4 h5 1.64
4 2 o8 p0 1.92
```

I want to sort by the first column. Afterwards I want Matlab to save the result in a new .txt-file or open Excel that I can use this table. Is that possible?

I tried to do this by using two for-loops but I get a lot of errors. Is there a simple way to do this mit Matlab?

Comment: is that your real data? so just one-digit letters and one-digit numbers?

Comment: @thewaywewalk: I added my real data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say you put your data in a file named `test.txt` formatted as you said

```
K L M N O
1 1 a1 3b 1.72
2 1 2c 4d 1.43
3 1 e3 5f 1.33
4 1 g4 h5 1.64
1 2 4i 4j 1.48
2 2 6k l8 2.33
3 2 m7 8n 2.12
4 2 o8 p0 1.92
```

Then the following code does what you want

```
% Read the file column by column according to the specified format (all strings in this case) and separated by a delimiter (a blank space in this case). The resulting `K`, `L`, ... are cells.
[K, L, M, N, O] = textread('test.txt', '%s %s %s %s %s', 'delimiter', ' ');     

% Remove the first element of the columns (i.e., the chars `K`, `L`, ...).
K(1) = [];
L(1) = [];
M(1) = [];
N(1) = [];
O(1) = [];

% Transform the cell into a matrix (a colum in this case) and sort it. The sorting returns also the position of the sorted column (variable `idx`).
[~, idx] = sort(cell2mat(K), 1, 'ascend');

% Put everything back together, re-adding the first letters and using the sorted indices.
X = [['K'; K(idx)], ['L'; L(idx)], ['M'; M(idx)], ['N'; N(idx)], ['O'; O(idx)]];

% Write to a xls file
xlswrite('newTest.xls', X);
```

**EDIT**

Here is another version that can read an arbitrary number of rows and columns. It is much more flexible, but since it involces a `for` loop it probably will be slower with a lot of rows. For instance, on my computer putting 1000 rows and 5 columns in the text file, the first code takes `1.1s`, while the second `2.2s`.

```
% Open the file, read it and close it.
fid = fopen('test.txt');
C = textscan(fid,'%s','delimiter','\n');
fclose(fid);

% textscan returns a 1-by-1 cell containing a N-by-1 cell array of strings.
% Since we used '\n' as delimiter, N will be the number of rows
C = C{1}; % explicitly take the cell

% Save the first row (with the names of the columns) an remove it for sorting
names = C(1,:);
C(1,:) = [];

% Sort the cells according to the rows
C = sort(C);

% Put the names back
C = [names; C];

% Split all the rows using the space as delimiter (default)
for i = 1 : numel(C)
    C{i} = strsplit(C{i});
end

% Convert it to table and write to a xls file
C = cell2table(C);
writetable(C,'newTest.xls','WriteVariableNames',false)
% 'WriteVariableNames' avoids that default headlines will be put in the xls
```

**EDIT 2**

The previous code considers all the inputs as strings, and therefore has problem sorting the rows properly (e.g., `10` would go before `2`).
This final solutions solves all the problems and it is even faster than the second solution.

```
% Read the file directly into a table
T = readtable('test.txt', 'Delimiter', ' ');

% Sort the rows according to the desired column (K in this case)
T = sortrows(T, 'K', 'ascend');

% To delete a column ('L' for instance)
T.L = [];

% Write the table into a xls file
writetable(T, 'newTest.xls', 'WriteVariableNames', true)
```

Comment: Can you please comment your code? What does "delimiter" stand for? I have an idea but I'm not sure. Thank you!

Comment: Done :) The delimiter is a keyword and specifies the char used to separate columns when reading the file. In my code it is just a blank space.

Comment: @ Simon: Is there a simple way to delete one or two entire columns? I would like to delete column M and O.

Comment: @Samuel Yes sure. Just don't add them to the matrix `X`, that is the one that will be written in the cls file.
`That is: X = [['K'; K(idx)], ['L'; L(idx)], ['N'; N(idx)]];`

Comment: @ Simon: I tried to work with your first code. My problem now is, that column R which I want to sort is like 001 002 003 004 005 006 007 008 009 010 011 012 001 002 003 etc. and not 1 2 3 4 5 6...1 2 3 4. I get a lot of errors if I try to sort numbers like 001 002. How can I solve that?

Comment: @Samuel I tried modifying column `K` with `001, 002, ...`. My second code works perfectly, so just use that. The first code needs some modification and can still work, but if you need to do other operations or modify your data again in the future, you will have to modify it again as well. I wrote the first code just to reply to your original question in an efficient way, without considering other cases. The second code, on the other hand, is very flexible and you can use it freely.

Comment: I would like to try your second code. But how can I sort the table for other columns? I would like to sort also column O. I can I do that?

Comment: @Samuel This is another thing that you didn't mention. Next time you ask a question you should be more precise and consider all possible cases you want to solve.
However, the third code should work for all the possible cases.

Comment: The last code is very fast and is perfect for what I want to do. I export the file to Excel and instead of 1.7 I get 1. July etc. Therefore I want to add an apostrophe in front of each value in the table like '1.7 or '4j to avoid the problems. I managed to do this using your first code. I just added two for-loops with 'X(i,j) = strcat('''', X(i,j));' But how can I do that with your last code?

Comment: @Samuel You can just change Excel format for dates. Anyway, just edit the column like this: `a = repmat('''',length(T.O),1);
T.O = [a, num2str(T.O), a];` If the answer satisfies you, please accept it.

Comment: Thank you! I just noticed that at some places in the table my variables are not separated by a single space but by two or more. Therefore I get errors. Is there a simple way in the last code to handle this problem?

Comment: Just edit the string (as in my previous comment) with `regexprep`: `regexprep(string, '\ *', ' ')`. Anyway, try to Google these kind of questions, you can easily find an answer in the Matlab documentation.

Comment: I tried for several hours to implement the regexprep function. I just began to work with Matlab. Therefore it is somehow difficult for me to work with functions I don't know. Could you please show me how I use regexprep in your code? Thank you!

Comment: @Samuel Let's say you want to edit the column `L`: `T.L = regexprep(T.L, '\ *', ' ');` and then you write the table as usual.

Comment: @ Simon: I get the following error: _Each line of a text file must have the same number of delimiters. T = readtable('test.txt', 'Delimiter', ' ');_ I get errors if I want to read my test.txt-file into Matlab if there is a column where my values are separated by two or more single spaces. Therefore the function _regexprep_ can not solve this problem. Or do I it wrong? Is there another possibility to handle this problems?

Comment: In this case my regexp does not work. Since your problem is now quite different from your original request, I suggest you to ask a new question.

Answer (score 0):

It can be rather inconvenient in MATLAB to handle files with mixed data type (as you have here: integers, strings, and floats). One option is to use [`textscan()`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/textscan.html), which takes a `formatSpec` argument to parse input into a cell array. This can be cumbersome if the number of columns is large, however, and it is not straightforward to write the data back to file. In those cases, I suggest the following solution, which is simple in concept but somewhat inelegant:

#### data.csv

I'll assume your data is plain-text in the following format:

```
1 1 a1 3b 1.72
2 1 2c 4d 1.43
3 1 e3 5f 1.33
4 1 g4 h5 1.64
1 2 4i 4j 1.48
2 2 6k l8 2.33
3 2 m7 8n 2.12
4 2 o8 p0 1.92
```

#### sort_csv.m

The script to sort the rows of the data according to the first column and write it to a new file:

```
% read the data, ignoring types
A = dlmread('data.csv', ' ');

% get indices of the first column in sorted order
[~, indices] = sort(A(:,1));

% read each line of the file as a string into a cell array
fid = fopen('data.csv', 'rt');
lines = textscan(fid, '%s', 'delimiter', '\n');
fclose(fid);

% store lines sorted by first column in a new cell array
lines_sorted = {lines{:}{indices}};

% write sorted data to a new csv
fid = fopen('data_sorted.csv', 'wt');
fprintf(fid, '%s\n', lines_sorted{:});
fclose(fid);
```

#### data_sorted.csv

The output:

```
1 1 a1 3b 1.72
1 2 4i 4j 1.48
2 1 2c 4d 1.43
2 2 6k l8 2.33
3 1 e3 5f 1.33
3 2 m7 8n 2.12
4 1 g4 h5 1.64
4 2 o8 p0 1.92
```

The magic here is in the line `s = {lines{:}{indices}}`. This is just using the indices (in order of the sorted first column) to index the lines in the file and packs the result into a new cell array.

Note: if your data were purely numeric (stored in matrix `A`), you could simply use `sortrows(A, 1)` to sort by the first column.

#### UPDATE:

The function `dlmread` used in this solution fails to to read the text file without error in MATLAB. It does, however, work in Octave.

Comment: My data is not separated by commas. Does it make any difference here?

Comment: Yes it does.  You can't use `csvread` because it assumes that your data is delimited by commas.  This answer won't work... but `csvread` technically performs a `dlmread` under the hood, so you would just use `dlmread` but specify a different delimiter.

Comment: I assumed the data you pasted was from an Excel file and could be easily exported to CSV. I updated the answer to handle the space-delimited case.

Comment: @ ixjlyons: I get some errors: >>Error using dlmread (line 138)
Mismatch between file and format string.
Trouble reading 'Numeric' field from file (row number 1, field number 3) ==> a1 3b 1.72\n<< What do I wrong?

Error in sort_csv (line 2)
A = dlmread('data.csv', ' ');

Comment: @Samuel: Sorry about that. I was testing this in Octave (don't have MATLAB at home), which is able to read the file with `dlmread` (albeit with "garbage" values for the entries like "a1", "6k", etc.). I recommend accepting Simon's answer, despite needing to supply a format for each column. The idea of reading a file with an arbitrary number of columns and mixed data type turns out to be rather unwieldy in MATLAB, unfortunately (note: there are some solutions such as [loadcell](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/1965-loadcell-m) on the file exchange).

Comment: @ixjlyons I edited my answer to deal with an arbitrary amount of rows and columns. The only "limitation" is that it considers all rows as string, but it is impossible to write a totally generic code. Anyway it should be easy to adapt it by changing the format in `textscan`.